# Refactoring a method in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I'm a new user (actually studying it in a course) in Smalltalk (Squeak).
I have a method to check if one rectangle equals to a given rectangle which looks like this:

```
isEqual:givenRec
    self a = givenRec a
    ifTrue: [
        self b = givenRec b
        ifTrue: [
            ^true
        ].
        ^false
    ].
    self b = givenRec a
    ifTrue: [
        self a = givenRec b
        ifTrue: [
            ^true
        ].
        ^false
    ].
    ^false
```

my question is - is there a way to better write this? for it to be more compact?

also - why cant I refer to `a` which is instanceVariableNames with self inside methods?
thanks for the help!

EDIT:

this is how the class is defined:

```
MyShape subclass: #MyTriangle
    instanceVariableNames: 'a b c'
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'Ex2'
```

`MyShape` simply derives from `Object` and has nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make that more compact, yes.

First, besides `#ifTrue:` there is also `#ifFalse:` and `#ifTrue:ifFalse:`, roughly having the effect of if-not--then and if--then--else.

But also, we already have a logical AND condition, so why not use that:

```
isEqual: givenRec

    (self a = givenRec a and: [self b = givenRec b])
        ifTrue: [^ true].
    (self b = givenRec a and: [self a = givenRec b])
        ifTrue: [^ true].
    ^false
```

With `#ifTrue:ifFalse:`

```
isEqual: givenRec

    (self a = givenRec a and: [self b = givenRec b])
        ifTrue: [^ true]
        ifFalse: [^ (self b = givenRec a and: [self a = givenRec b])]
```

Also, we can do the return around the whole statement:

```
isEqual: givenRec

    ^ (self a = givenRec a and: [self b = givenRec b])
        ifTrue: [true]
        ifFalse: [self b = givenRec a and: [self a = givenRec b]]
```

But `ifTrue: [true]` is a bit redundant, let's use `#or:`

```
isEqual: givenRec

    ^ (self a = givenRec a and: [self b = givenRec b]) or: 
      [self b = givenRec a and: [self a = givenRec b]]
```

Nice and sweet, we also see the logical structure pretty easily.
(note that I diverge from common formatting styles to point out the similarities and differences in the two logical expressions).

We now have only one return `^`, no `#ifTrue:…`

---

For the instance variable question:

When you define some instance variables in the class like you did, you can use them literally in your code to access them:

```
Object subclass: #Contoso
    instanceVariableNames: 'things'
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'Examples'
```

```
isThingPlusThreeSameAs: anObject

    ^ thing + 3 = anObject
```

But typically, it is better to refer to instance variables via *getters* and *setters*, commonly called *accessors*. You have to write them manually or use the 'create inst var accessor' menu item of the *second* context menu (via “more…”) of a class in the browser:

[image]
[image]

This will generate accessor methods of the form

```
thing

    ^ thing
```

```
thing: anObject

    thing := anObject
```

and you can use them in other methods like this

```
isThingPlusThreeSameAs: anObject

    ^ self thing + 3 = anObject
```

Comment: thanks, i edited my question - added the class definition

Comment: another question @Tobias - how do i draw a rectangle on the screen given its two edges' lengths?

Comment: So your class looks good, It now really depends on the code you had for the comparison. ~~Please make a new question for the Instance variable question~~ EDIT my answer

Comment: Ah for the Drawing a rectangle, please make a new question, it's easier to answer that way

Comment: here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521633/drawing-a-rectangle-in-smalltalk-squeak

Answer (score 0):

I would have written the method as

```
equals: aTriangle
  a = aTriangle a ifFalse: [^false].
  b = aTriangle b ifFalse: [^false].
  ^c = aTriangle c
```

Note by the way that I'm using the selector `#equals:` rather than `#isEqual:` because the latter doesn't read so well in English (it would if it had been `#isEqualTo:`, but `#equals:` is shorter).

Another remark I would add here is that you could have redefined `#=` instead of adding a new comparison selector. In that case, however, you have to pay attention to a couple of additional things:

```
= aTriangle
  self class = aTriangle class ifFalse: [^false].
  a = aTriangle a ifFalse: [^false].
  b = aTriangle b ifFalse: [^false].
  ^c = aTriangle c
```

The reason for the class check is to make sure that `#=` is robust, i.e., it doesn't signal a `MessageNotUnderstood` exception. The other thing is that every time you (re)define `#=` you should also (re)define `#hash` in such a way that `t1 hash = t2 hash` whenever `t1 = t2`. For example

```
hash
  ^(a hash + b hash + c hash) hash
```

Note that this proposal for `#hash` is not the best one, but this is not the place to discuss the problem of writing good `#hash` functions.

**UPDATE**

Here is my version when the order doesn't matter

```
equals: aTriangle
  | sides |
  self = aTriangle ifTrue: [^true].
  sides := Set with: a with: b with: c.
  (sides includes: aTriangle a) ifFalse: [^false].
  (sides includes: aTriangle b) ifFalse: [^false].
  ^(sides includes: aTriangle c)
```

The first comparison is to speed up the method avoiding the `Set` when the order is the same.

Comment: you cannot use the early return when one vertex differs, because he wants to compare vertices ignoring the order, so (a, b, c) = (c, b, a)

Comment: I don't like having two different notions of equality, one with ordered vertices in #= and the other with the set in #equalsTo:..

Comment: In #equals, the set is defined with 1 instead of a vertex

Comment: @CarlosE.Ferro Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not write it like this, but there are situations where meta programming this is useful

```
isEqual: givenRec
  #(a b c) do: [ :selector |
    (self perform: selector) = (givenRec perform: selector) ifFalse: [
      ^false]].
  ^true
```