# Drawing A Rectangle in Smalltalk Squeak

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

given two integer variables 'a' and 'b' in a rectangle class, how do you draw a rectangle?
I'm new to smalltalk and im studying it for a course.
thanks!

Comment: We need to know your Smalltalk dialect, because drawing is different for each

Comment: im not sure what you mean by dialect - im using squeak smalltalk

Comment: Ah yes, I see , sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Squeak uses *Morphic* as its default UI. So the simplest thing would be to create a *Morph*:

```
RectangleMorph new
    extent: 300@200;
    openInWorld
```

Evaluate all three lines at once. This creates a new `RectangleMorph` instance, sets its extent to a `Point` created from `300` and `200` (by sending the message `@` to `300` with an argument of `200`), and also sends it the `openInWorld` message so it appears in the world. It will open in the top-left screen corner. We could have sent it the `position:` message with another `Point` argument, but you can as easily just grab it with your mouse pointer and move it anywhere you please.

In your class you might use `a@b` to create the extent point (assuming `a` and `b` are the rectangle's width and height in pixels).

*Morphic* is nice because it creates real objects that you can manipulate interactively, e.g. by cmd-clicking to bring up a *Halo*. If you don't want that, you can also paint on the screen directly. E.g.:

```
Display fill: (0@0 extent: 300@200) fillColor: Color red.
```

... where `Display` is a global *Form* instance (containing a *Bitmap*) refering to the whole Squeak display. But since that expression just puts pixels on the screen, they will be overwritten quickly. *Morphs*, in contrast, know how to redraw themselves whenever needed.

It's also possible to create your own *Morph* subclass and implement a custom `drawOn:` method. But that would be overkill for something as simple as showing a rectangle.